# What can I use extra Project Cores for?

Tags: league-of-legends

During a recent League of Legends event, players could collect Project Cores to use in the crafting area of the game. But, now that I have all of the icons (pretty sure the event is over as well) what can I use the remaining 8 Project Cores I have for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the official [FAQ](https://support.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/210155266-PROJECT-DISRUPTION-FAQ)

> All PROJECT content will stay in your Hextech Crafting inventory once the event is over. If you prefer a tidy inventory, you'll be able to disenchant all PROJECT materials into a little bit of essence.

However I haven't found out how to disenchant anything in the client yet. I have a couple cores and some cache fragments myself and don't see a disenchant option.

[EDIT](http://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/help-support/EcTEEE61-cant-disenchant-project-items):

> <strike>The current plan per our project disruption guide is to make leftover items disenchantable. **It doesn't seem to be enabled just yet!** I don't have an eta on when that will be, but hang tight!</strike>

EDIT 2: It is now enabled, you can disenchant leftover PROJECT items for 2 orange essence each.